# Run local executable file on remote servers with Capistrano

Tags: capistrano

I have a pretty long `.sh` file in my Capistrano `tools` directory that is intended to be executed on servers, not locally. Is there a simple way to execute this file on servers inside a Capistrano task without manually copying it on each server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the script is in your repository, you can create a custom task which allows you to do exactly that. Something like:

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Run custom command'
  task :run_custom_command do
    on roles(:app) do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute release_path.join('tools/command.sh')
    end
  end

  before :publishing, :run_custom_command

end
```